# Mock a method call when it is called in private method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a public method say `a()`, which is calling a private method say `B()` present in same class.

Now my method `B` (private) calling an external method (say `search()`), which returns List of Strings. Based on the list returned; I have to perform some logic in method `B`.

When I am mocking the external method call (mock `search`) with some list values, mockito returned the empty list; not the list which I am setting while mocking this external call.

I am not getting why, I am getting empty list.

Below is the sample code:

```
        public class ABC {
            @Autowired
            private External ext;

            // method 1 
            public void A(String id){
                // method private call
                B(id);
            }

            private String B(String id) {            
                // do something
                // external method call
                List myList = ext.search(id);    // from here we getting empty list
                if(myList != null && 
                    !myList.isEmpty()) {
                    // do some logic here, 
                }
            }
        }

    Sample Test Class:

   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)        
   Class MyTest{

            @Autowire
            ABC abc;           

            @Test
            public void myTest() {
                // construct the mocked object
                List resultList = new ArrayList();
                resultList.add("Java");
                resultList.add("C");
                resultList.add("Python");
                // mock the external API
                Mockito.when(externalMock.search(Mockito.any(String.class)).
                thenReturn(resultList);
                // call method A on ABC class
                abc.A(); // public method A call                
            }  
        }
```

// Mocked External class

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class ExternalMock {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public External getExternal() {
        return Mockito.mock(External.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So generally with mocking frameworks the idea is to replace a dependency of your class, in this case `External` with a simplified replacement implementation so that you can exclude the behaviour of the dependency from your test. In order to do this, you need to specify the interface to your external dependency, in your case perhaps by creating an `IExternal` interface and injecting that into your constructor. When you are instantiating the actual version of the class you can pass in `External` implementing `IExternal` and in your test case you can pass in a mock instance of an `IExternal` class.

Here is [an article](https://github.com/TechnionYP5777/SmartCity-Market/wiki/Dependency-Injection-and-Unit-Testing-With-Mockito) with an example of injecting a mocked dependency into a class using Mockito.

Comment: In my code "External" is the interface and I am injecting via auto wiring. in sample code , it is mentioned using new().

Comment: Should the `externalMock.search(Mockito.any(String.class)` be `externalMock.search()` as there is no string parameter?

Answer (score 0):

`External` should be explicitly injected into the subject class.

```
public class ABC {
    private External ext;

    @Autowire
    public ABC(External ext) {
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    // method 1 
    public void A(String id){
        // method private call
        B(id);
    }

    private String B(String id) {
        // do something
        // external method call
        List myList = ext.search(id);
        if(myList != null && 
            !myList.isEmpty()) {
            // ... do some logic here, 
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow mocks to be substituted when testing in isolation.

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        //Arrange
        List resultList = new ArrayList();
        resultList.add("Java");
        resultList.add("C");
        resultList.add("Python");

        // mock the external API
        External externalMock = Mockito.mock(External.class);
        Mockito.when(externalMock.search(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(resultList);

        ABC abc = new ABC(externalMock);
        String input = "Hello world";

        //Act
        abc.A(input); // public method A call

        //Assert
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: After mocking the search API in Test class, method B will have the empty list (myList); not the one which i set (resultList) while mocking the API.

Comment: Look at the modification made to the class. If mocked dependency is injected into class and the mock is configured correctly then the `resultList` will be returned.